# DataContext System.Security.VerificationException error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

I am maintaining Windows Phone 7 application. Everything worked fine. Everything still works fine on WP 8. But on WP7 app breaks. I have .sdf database in project. Below is the code I use to stream it in isolated storage.

```
 using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets\\myDB.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                    {
                        // Create a stream for the new file in the local folder.
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("myDB.sdf"))
                        {
                            // Initialize the buffer.
                            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                            int bytesRead = -1;

                            // Copy the file from the installation folder to the local folder. 
                            while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var listOfCities = ModelUtil.GetCities().OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

This is GetCities method

```
        public static List<ListPickerData> GetCities()
    {
        List<ListPickerData> cities = new List<ListPickerData>();

        using (myDataContext context = new myDataContext(ModelUtil.ConnectionString))
        {
            var data = context.Cities.ToList();

           ...
        }

        return cities;
    }
```

And this is where it breaks:
[image]

Does anyone know what happened? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract the database file from the working WP8 install, and re-add to your project. Also, what does your connection string look like?

Comment: I tried extracting database and adding it back. It doesnt work. This is my connection string: public const string ConnectionString = @"isostore:/myDB.sdf"

Comment: Feel free to email me a repro app, and I will look closer